# Android | Parse.com | Query User Collection with another Collection

Tags: android, parse-platform

i have basic question. Iam using parse android SDK to retrieve some data from backend. I have 2 collections : "User" and "Photo". What i want to do is that i want to query "Photo" collection which contains some data about image and join that against "User" collection and get some info about owner of picture. Please see code below:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryInner = ParseUser.getQuery();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Photo");
    query.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("owner", "username", queryInner);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> resultSet, ParseException exception) {
            if (exception == null) {
                parsqQueryResult = new ArrayList<ObjectUserPhoto>();
                ObjectUserPhoto row = new ObjectUserPhoto();
                Log.e("size",String.valueOf(resultSet.size()));
                for (int a = 0; a < resultSet.size(); a++) {   
                    row = new ObjectUserPhoto();
//this works
 row.setDescription(resultSet.get(a).getString(Constants.DB_COL_USER_PHOTOS_DESCRIPTION));
//this is not working
Log.e("username",String.valueOf(resultSet.get(a).getString("col_from_user_table")));
                    parsqQueryResult.add(row);
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

So basically iam able to acces columns from "Photo" collection, but iam not able to acces any column from "User" collection. How can i acces data from "User" collection ??
Thanks
Martin

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the columns of your Photo class in Parse? One of the columns in your Photo class should have a type of ParseObject which references to the _User class

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. Our DB doesnt contains pointers. Is it possible to do that without pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you mentioned that you are not using pointers. I assume that you are just storing the id of the ParseUser objects.

Given a ParseObject's ID, you can retrieve an object by issuing a ParseQuery and passing the ID. Refer to [this](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-retrieving) document.

However, I do not see any reason why you would want to store just the ID and not the Pointer to the object. Imagine if you want to display the information on a list then that means for every item you will need to perform a ParseQuery.

If you store a Pointer then you can leverage on the "include" method (see it [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-relational) at the bottom part of the "Relational Queries"). This allows you to include the actual object the Pointer is pointing to. So in your case, the results of the Photo query will include the User objects too.

And lastly, I suggest that you read through at least the whole Objects and Queries sections of the documentation as you would learn the basics on how to use the SDK.

Comment: Thanks mussharapp, tables are already designed by another developers, therefore i was searching for solution how to do this without using pointers, but obviously it's not possible.